# Why does the program launch one way but not the other?

Tags: 10.04, launcher, alacarte

I have this problem creating a launcher. I downloaded a tar.gz and extracted it: CaveStoryPlus from the Humble Bundle 4. If I double click the executable  in Nautilus, it launches. If I run `~/CaveStoryPlus/CaveStory+` in the terminal it doesn't launch but if I run `cd CaveStoryPlus && ./CaveStory+` it launches. Then if I try to create an application launcher in Main Menu (alacarte), nothing works for me even if I state "Application in terminal" with the above command.

(Edited post to show I ran the command with the full path)

Answer (score 1):

You need to be in the working directory for you to be able to issue `./CaveStory+`, UNLESS the directory is added to the `$PATH` environment variable. Once that is done, you will be able to just call `./CaveStory+` from any directory.

To just edit the $PATH variable in one terminal instance and set it as a Global Variable, you can do `export PATH=$PATH:/absolute-path-to-cavestory-directory/`

If you want it to be a permanent change, add the same `export PATH=$PATH:/absolute-path-to-cavestory-directory/` to your `~/.bashrc` file (preferably at the end of the file, just to keep track of what you added personally)

Take a look at the [Ubuntu Community Documentation on environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) or this [blogpost](http://www.2buntu.com/2011/09/20/setting-environment-variables-in-linux-using-bash-shell-how-to/) for more information about environment variables.

Comment: Sorry, I omitted to mention that I tried running the command with the full path. The strange thing is that I already tried adding the path to my .bashrc, sourced it and when I try to execute the command the shell can't find it.

Comment: no joy. i even tried with quotes around it.

Comment: Instead of `~/CaveStoryPlus/` try `/home/username/CaveStoryPlus/ `